# Working with Flux in a Scheduled Task

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

I am working on a Spring Webflux project and have encountered an issue trying to publish and consume Flux's in a Scheduled Task.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20*1000)
fun updateNews() {
    try {
        logger.info("Automatic Update at: ${LocalDateTime.now()}")
        articleRepository.saveAll(
                sourceRepository.findAll().publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                        .map { source -> source.generate() }
                        .flatMap { it?.read() ?: Flux.empty() })
                        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)
        ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    } catch(e: Throwable) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error in Scheduler", e)
    }
}
```

My configured Scheduler:

```
ConcurrentTaskScheduler(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3))
```

This task will never completed unless I intentionally block on the end:

```
.then().block()
```

I originally did not bother with the direct reference to publish/subscribe to the Schedulers, and I have tried all of the options that seemed reasonable to no effect.

My log event occurs, but it seems as though when the thread for this task from the scheduler dies, the flux's are trashes as well; even though they should be in their own thread pool once I have specified the publishOn and subscribeOn behavior?

I would like to make this action completely reactive, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Scheduled` isn't integrated with `Flux`, so it wouldn't know what to do with the `Flux` should you return it. Combine that with the fact that in Reactor (and Reactive Streams in general), nothing generally happens until you `subscribe()`, and you can start to see what went wrong.

`block()` is actually a form of `subscribe()`, that's why it works once you add it to the code. it is actually probably the best option here since you need to bridge a reactive piece of code (from the `ReactiveRepository`) into the imperative blocking world (your `@Scheduled fun`).

Comment: Is there a better way to accomplish such a thing in general?

To generalize the problem: Having "publishers" that aren't reactive, and needing to pull them into your data in as continuous a way as possible.

Comment: I see now that I was operating under the false assumption that the `saveAll()` acting as a consumer would have caused the triggering of the flux chain.

I do not believe I really need to `block()`, as I do not care at all about the response from the `saveAll()` call, so `subscribe()` may be my best option.

Comment: ah, indeed if you want to fire-and-forget. that said, in case of error it would probably beneficial to provide an error handler to the `subscribe(...)`